# Drupal 7 redirect different domain name to different user page

Tags: drupal, redirect, dns

I user drupal 7 to build a site that users can customise their user profile page.

Then i use pathauto to rewrite the url alias to mydrupalsite.com/user/username. 
what i want to do next is:

If a user get his own domain name such as www.username.com and point it to my server, how can I redirect www.username.com to mydrupalsite.com/user/username. 
can i use WHM to do it or i need to modify .httaccess file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Server-side setup is a must. So setup your server to point all requests to any domain, to base of the Drupal site.
For an example, if your drupal site is example.com, example.net and example.org should point to the base domain. As you have cPanel, it's similar to "parking" example.net and example.org in example.com's public root.

Then, depending on your need, you have 2 choices. [subdomain](http://drupal.org/project/subdomain) module or Domain Access module. 
Subdomain module is almost for your use-case and it creates **subdomains** for each user and it can handle bootstrap depending on requested domain.
Domain Access, is actively developing and you can use the (pre-release) [Domain User](http://drupalcode.org/project/domain_user.git/tree/refs/heads/master) module to assign domains automatically. But Domain Access module itself comes with many useful sub-modules and integrates with [Rules][4] module to do the redirection.

But none of these are "pretty" way to  do your exact usecase. 
You could modify the Subdomain module to suit your needs such as integrating with WHM to create domain parking, etc.
There are many cPanel integrations for Drupal but I don't know much about them.

Comment: Thx for the reply, i had a look at the two modules. seems to me they r more for sub-domain/multi site domain function. What i want is a bit different. What i want is just a way to point a totally different domain name such as www.david.com to one of my drupal user page such as mydrupalsite.com/user/11.